Facet wrap for soil profile collection in AQP
I am using the package Algorithms for Quantitative Pedology [https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/aqp/index.html] which presents soil profile collections. I am trying to display two different parameters (Pb and Mn) in one figure for the same profile similar to a facet_wrap in ggplot.I'd like the profiles side by side one for Pb and one for Mn. Any help would be appreciated!
soil_data <- data.frame(rating=1:4,
                             id=c('1', '1', '1', '1'),
                             name=c('A', 'B', 'Ag2', 'Cg1'),
                             top = c('0', '5', '10', '15'),
                             bottom = c('5', '10','15','20'),
                             Pb = c('3.4', '0', '2', '5.6'),
                             Mn = c('4', '0.1', '3.2', '6'))

soil_data$top <- as.numeric(soil_data$top)    
soil_data$bottom <- as.numeric(soil_data$bottom) 
soil_data <- soil_data %>% mutate(height = bottom - top)

#create soil profile collection object
depths(soil_data) <- id ~ top + bottom

#dice into 20 1cm slices and plot with Pb as color
spc <- dice(soil_data, fm= 0:20 ~ Pb + Mn)
plotSPC(spc, color = 'Pb')



Tried duplicating the profile but this didn't work
spc2 <- duplicate(spc[1, ], times = 2)
par(mar = c(0,2,0,1))
plotSPC(spc2, color = 'Pb', 'Mn')


You're getting an error due to the string Mn. It plots if you remove this element. Only one element can be assigned to color (if that's what you were trying to do.) Right now you aren't going to get a profile for Pb and Mn, because these are columns in the data. If I'm not mistaken, the profiles are built based on the rows.

@Kerry Kuntz – It's unclear (at least to me) how you want the combined figure to look; a better description, if not a drawing, would help.
